# Calling WCF Service from both Jquery and a Service Reference

Tags: wcf, jquery

My requirement is to be able to call a simple WCF service from both Jquery Ajax and also by adding a service reference.

This is easily done in asmx services and I am really struggling to see how WCF can be "better" and "more powerful" when this simple task is proving so difficult and convoluted.

I have followed various tutorials such as:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/540169/CallingplusWCFplusServicespluswithplusjQuery-e2-80
http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2011/11/jquery-calling-a-wcf-service-from-jquery/#.UihK6saa5No

However I always end up with a solution where I can call by ServiceReference but not Jquery or vice-versa.

For the following simple service, can anyone please provide me with the:

- Necessary attributes to decorate the service and interface with
- Web.config ServiceModel sections with all bindings/endpoints/behaviours/etc

to facilitate calling the WCF service from both Jquery (ajax) and by adding a service reference in a .net project?

Or should I just go back to good old simple (but apparently less powerful) amsx?

Comment: What is the error you get when calling from jquery?>

Answer (score 0):

I have used webhttpbinding for the WCF service to be called from javascript.

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WCF.TestWCF" behaviorConfiguration="TestWCFBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCF.ITestWCF" behaviorConfiguration="TestWCFEndPointBehaviour"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestWCFBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestWCFEndPointBehaviour">
      <enableWebScript/>
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

service:

```
namespace WCF{
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "Saranya")]  
public interface ITestWCF
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    String HelloWorld();  
}}   



namespace WCF{
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =
    AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class TestWCF:ITestWCF
{
    public String HelloWorld()
    {                                  
        return "Hello World!!";
    }      
}



    Using Jquery:


 $.post("http://localhost:26850/Service1.svc/HelloWorld?", null, fnsuccesscallback, "xml");
 function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
                    alert(data.xml);          

    }
```

using service reference:

```
 obj = new Saranya.ITestWCF();
                    obj.HelloWorld(fnsuccesscallback);
 function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
                    alert(data.xml);

                }
```